# GeckoFX - WinForms - javascript:print()

Tags: winforms, printing, geckofx

i just created a win form app
with a Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser on it
when i navigate to a page with a anchor that has the href attribute set to 
javascript:print() and click on it, the print dialog is displayed, but it turns out that when i hit cancel button on that dialog
the Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser is destroyed , i mean the control receives a WM_DETROY message
any clue of what is could be happen here?
how i can prevent it?
i modified the gecko fx Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser windows procedure and catch and bypass that windows message but it seems that is not helping
btw i am using xulrunner-11.0.en-US.win32 and geckofx-11.dll
regards

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the firefox code, It looks like firefox is sending the WM_DESTROY message.

```
nsPrintingPromptService::ShowPrintDialog(nsIDOMWindow *parent, nsIWebBrowserPrint *webBrowserPrint, nsIPrintSettings *printSettings)
{
    NS_ENSURE_ARG(parent);

    HWND hWnd = GetHWNDForDOMWindow(parent);
    NS_ASSERTION(hWnd, "Couldn't get native window for PRint Dialog!");

    return NativeShowPrintDialog(hWnd, webBrowserPrint, printSettings);
}



nsresult NativeShowPrintDialog(HWND                aHWnd,
                               nsIWebBrowserPrint* aWebBrowserPrint,
                               nsIPrintSettings*   aPrintSettings)
{
  PrepareForPrintDialog(aWebBrowserPrint, aPrintSettings);

  nsresult rv = ShowNativePrintDialog(aHWnd, aPrintSettings);
  if (aHWnd) {
    ::DestroyWindow(aHWnd);
  }

  return rv;
}
```

I'm not sure why it would do this.

Some options to fix this:

- turn on "print.always_print_silent"
- provide and register your own nsIPrintingPromptService
- provide and register your own nsIWindowWatcher service.

The nsIWindowWatcher way looks like the proper way to do this looking at GetHWNDForDOMWindow:

```
HWND
nsPrintingPromptService::GetHWNDForDOMWindow(nsIDOMWindow *aWindow)
{
    nsCOMPtr<nsIWebBrowserChrome> chrome;
    HWND hWnd = NULL;

    // We might be embedded so check this path first
    if (mWatcher) {
        nsCOMPtr<nsIDOMWindow> fosterParent;
        if (!aWindow) 
        {   // it will be a dependent window. try to find a foster parent.
            mWatcher->GetActiveWindow(getter_AddRefs(fosterParent));
            aWindow = fosterParent;
        }
        mWatcher->GetChromeForWindow(aWindow, getter_AddRefs(chrome));
    }

    if (chrome) {
        nsCOMPtr<nsIEmbeddingSiteWindow> site(do_QueryInterface(chrome));
        if (site) 
        {
            HWND w;
            site->GetSiteWindow(reinterpret_cast<void **>(&w));
            return w;
        }
    }
```